# BaseAdapter in ListFragment (or Fragment) doesn't working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I tried to show a listview in a Activity and it worked, but when I try to show the same listview from a fragment called from a actionbar tab my program doesn't run. I had tried to use both Fragment and ListFragment but didn't work even with some examples that I found on Internet. Can anyone help me?

The error that I'm getting when I try to start the active that is with the actionbar start with this:

01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.TelaPrincipal}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

So, I need to create any List on TelaPrincipal.java?

TelaPrincipal.java

```
package com.app;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TelaPrincipal extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tela_principal);





        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar(); 
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        //setupTabs();

        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab tab1 = ab.newTab();
        tab1.setTag("Professores");
        tab1.setText("Professores");
        tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.ac_professores);
        tab1.setTabListener(new NavegacaoTabs(new FListaProfessores()));
        ab.addTab(tab1);

        //Adicionar outras Tabs depois

    }


    private class NavegacaoTabs implements TabListener {
        private Fragment frag;

        public NavegacaoTabs(Fragment frag){
            this.frag = frag;
        }



        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Script", "onTabReselected()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tab.getTag().toString());

            FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fts.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, frag);

            fts.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fts.remove(frag);
            fts.commit();

        }
        }

}
```

tela_principal.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Professor.java

```
package com.app;

public class Professor {
    private String nome;
    private String disciplina;


    private int avaliacoes;
    private int aprovacao;
    private int reprovacao;



    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDisciplina() {
        return disciplina;
    }
    public void setDisciplina(String disciplina) {
        this.disciplina = disciplina;
    }




    public int getAvaliacoes() {
        return avaliacoes;
    }
    public void setAvaliacoes(int avaliacoes) {
        this.avaliacoes = avaliacoes;
    }
    public int getAprovacao() {
        return aprovacao;
    }
    public void setAprovacao(int aprovacao) {
        this.aprovacao = aprovacao;
    }
    public int getReprovacao() {
        return reprovacao;
    }
    public void setReprovacao(int reprovacao) {
        this.reprovacao = reprovacao;
    }




}
```

professor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/vermelho_linha">
        </View>

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="89">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

             <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/professor_tvNome"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:textSize="28sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/preto"
                            android:text="TextView" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

             <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/professor_tvDisciplina"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:maxLines="2"
                         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                         android:textSize="15sp"
                         android:ellipsize="end"
                         android:textColor="@color/preto"
                         android:text="TextView" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

              <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                  <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/professor_tvAvalicaoes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/preto"
                        android:text="TextView" />


                    </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                  <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/professor_tvAprovacoes"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                         android:textSize="15sp"
                         android:textColor="@color/verde"
                         android:text="TextView" />


                    </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

ProfessorAdapter.java

```
package com.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;




import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfessorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Professor> lista;


    public ProfessorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Professor> lista){
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Professor professor = lista.get(position);
        View layout;



        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.professor, null);
        }
        else{
            layout = convertView;
        }

        TextView nomeProfessor = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.professor_tvNome);
        nomeProfessor.setText(professor.getNome());

        TextView avaliacoesProfessor = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.professor_tvAvalicaoes);
        avaliacoesProfessor.setText(professor.getAvaliacoes() + " avaliações");

        TextView disciplinaProfessor = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.professor_tvDisciplina);
        disciplinaProfessor.setText(professor.getDisciplina());


        float porcentagemAprovacao = ( (float) professor.getAprovacao() / (float) professor.getAvaliacoes() ) *100;
        TextView aprovacoesProfessor = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.professor_tvAprovacoes);



        if(porcentagemAprovacao >50){

            aprovacoesProfessor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));

        }
        else{

            aprovacoesProfessor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }

        String porcento = String.format("%.1f", porcentagemAprovacao);
        aprovacoesProfessor.setText(porcento + "% aprovações");




        return layout;
    }

}
```

FListaProfessores.java    << I think that the error is in this file, I've made many changes and tried everything without success, that was the last attemptive that I made.

```
package com.app;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FListaProfessores extends ListFragment {

    ProfessorAdapter adapter;
    private static ArrayList<Professor> professores = new ArrayList<Professor>();
    private static ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        fillProfessores(professores);
        adapter = new ProfessorAdapter(getActivity(), professores);



        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Professor temp = (Professor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String nomeProfessor = (String) temp.getNome();

                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Professor " + nomeProfessor + " clicado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }



        });


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flista_professores, null, false); 


        return (view);
    }





public void fillProfessores(ArrayList<Professor> professores){

        Professor professor = new Professor();
        professor.setNome("Professor 1");
        professor.setDisciplina("Materia 1");
        professor.setAvaliacoes(125);
        professor.setAprovacao(83);
        professores.add(professor);

        Professor professor2 = new Professor();
        professor2.setNome("Professor 2");
        professor2.setDisciplina("Materia 2");
        professor2.setAvaliacoes(233);
        professor2.setAprovacao(182);
        professores.add(professor2);


    }

}
```

flista_professres.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    
             
             <ListView
              android:id="@+id/lista_professores"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              android:divider="@color/azul_linha"
              android:dividerHeight="1dp"
              style="@style/DropDownListView.Cadernotema">

           </ListView>
           

 </LinearLayout>
```

LogCat messages

```js
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.TelaPrincipal}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:961)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
01-09 03:10:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You posted all of your code but didn't say what is the problem. Just saying "Not working" is not going to help.

Comment: I've updated where I think that is the problem. The problem basically is that when I run this code on a Activity using ListView it runs and on Fragment or ListFragment it crashes when the ActivityHost is called.

Comment: Please put the logcat trace of crash

Comment: I don't know how to show the "11 more.." messages, is that suficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its crashing because you need to have the id of listview as `android.R.id.list`

Change layout xml `flista_professores` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:divider="@color/azul_linha"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        style="@style/DropDownListView.Cadernotema">
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I got errors "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix". I added "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" on the listView and it worked! Thank you very much man, I was struggling with that for two days, reading all java files again and again.

Comment: You know most of the time logcat error is sufficient enough to get the error. Just need to understand it.

Comment: Just a note, in my code there is no LinearLayout, just the ListView with the list name, and it is working, does make difference add the linearlayout or not?

Answer (score 0):

Logcat said "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

According to doc[ListFragmant](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

```
your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)
```

Is it in flista_professores layout?